# bash script: how log in as root or extract .IFO from .ISO image without first mounting it

Tags: bash, authentication, copy, root

I've written a bash script that downloads, repairs and unrars files via nzb files.  Most often the result is a VIDEO_TS folder or an .ISO file.  I am now extending this script so that it will encode either of those results using mplayer/mencoder.  But if I'm trying to encode an .ISO that contains subtitles, I also need to copy an .IFO file from the .ISO or mplayer will not display the subtitles properly.  Mencoder will not extract the .IFO, only the .SUB and .IDX files.

The only way I know to extract files from an .ISO requires first mounting it as root.  As this script takes several hours and is a resource hog I like to run it at night unattended.  So I can't log in as root if it should be necessary.

So, in a bash script, is it possible to log in as root entirely within the script, or, alternatively, is it possible to copy files from an .ISO without having to mount it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fuseiso](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso/) to mount iso images as a regular user. It's in Debian and Ubuntu.

Then just issue `fuseiso iso.img /mount/point`.

Alternatively, just set up passwordless `sudo` (with NOPASSWD) for the user running the script and prepend privileged commands with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isoinfo`, as well. For example; `isoinfo -l image.iso` will list all files, and `isoinfo -x some/file.txt image.iso` will extract a single file from the image. In Fedora, it's part of the `genisoimage` package; it seems that it's hosted at http://cdrkit.org/ and probably part of `debburn` on Debian?

Comment: Small correction, actually its isoinfo not isodump that extracts files.

Comment: ah, sorry, thanks. I typed `man isodump` and didn't realize it had multiple commands on one manpage … ! corrected answer above.